Origin of $L_\varepsilon^\nu$ in Lars Hörmander's proof of the kernel theorem in "The Analysis of Linear Partial Differential Operators I"
Context
In the proof of the kernel theorem Hörmander takes open subsets $X_i\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{n_i}$ ($i=1,2$) and relatively compact sets $Y_i\subset X_i$ (that means $\overline{Y}_i$ is compact and $\overline{Y}_i\subset X_i$). He then defines
$$ K_{ \varepsilon } (x_1, x_2) := \Big\langle\mathscr{K} \Big( \varepsilon^{ -n_2 } \psi_2 \Big( \frac{ x_2 - \cdot }{ \varepsilon } \Big) \Big), \varepsilon^{ -n_1 } \psi_1 \Big( \frac{ x_1 - \cdot }{ \varepsilon } \Big)\Big\rangle, \hspace{7mm} (x_1,x_2)\in Y_1\times Y_2$$
for small $\varepsilon>0$. Here $\mathscr{K}: \mathcal{D}(X_2) \rightarrow \mathcal{D}'( X_1 )$ is a linear and continous map and $\psi_i\in\mathcal{D}_{K_i}(X_i)$ ($K_i$ is a compact neighbourhood of $Y_i$) with $\psi_i\geq0$, $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\psi_i=1$ and $|x_i|\leq1$ for every $x_i\in\mathrm{supp}(\psi_i)$.
For calculating $\partial K_{ \varepsilon } (x_1,x_2) / \partial \varepsilon$ he uses the equality
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \varepsilon}\Big[\varepsilon^{-n}\varphi\Big(\frac{x}{\varepsilon}\Big)\Big]
        = \sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\Big[\varepsilon^{-n}\varphi_i\Big(\frac{x}{\varepsilon}\Big)\Big], \hspace{5mm} \varphi_i(x):=-x_i\varphi(x)$$
which holds for every $\varphi\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$.
With that he claims that
$$\frac{ \partial }{ \partial \varepsilon } K_{ \varepsilon } (x_1, x_2) = \sum_{ \nu } \frac{ \partial }{ \partial x_{ \nu } } L_{ \varepsilon }^{ \nu } ( x_1, x_2 )$$
where $\nu$ runs over all the coordinates of $(x_1,x_2)$ and $L_{ \varepsilon }^{ \nu }$ is just $K_{ \varepsilon }$ but replacing $\psi_1$ or $\psi_2$ with $-x_\nu \psi_1$ or $-x_\nu \psi_2$.
Question
By calculating $\frac{ \partial }{ \partial \varepsilon } K_{ \varepsilon } (x_1, x_2)$ on my own I get the factor $-x_\nu/\varepsilon$ and not $-x_\nu$. With the upper equation I get
$$\frac{ \partial }{ \partial \varepsilon } \Big[ \varepsilon^{ -n_i } \psi_i  \Big( \frac{ x_i - x }{ \varepsilon } \Big) \Big] = \sum_{ j = 1 }^{ n_i } \frac{ \partial }{ \partial x_j } \Big[ \varepsilon^{ -n_i - 1 } \cdot ( -x_j ) \psi_i  \Big( \frac{ x_i - x }{ \varepsilon } \Big) \Big]$$
where $x_j$ is the $j$th coordinate of $x$ (and not $x_i$!). So I have different result than Hörmander and I do not understand why. With my understanding of the proof I expect
$$\frac{ \partial }{ \partial \varepsilon } \Big[ \varepsilon^{ -n_i } \psi_i  \Big( \frac{ x_i - x }{ \varepsilon } \Big) \Big] = \sum_{ j = 1 }^{ n_i } \frac{ \partial }{ \partial x_j } \Big[ \varepsilon^{ -n_i } \cdot ( -(x_i)_j ) \psi_i  \Big( \frac{ x_i - x }{ \varepsilon } \Big) \Big]$$
where $(x_i)_j$ is the $j$th entry of $x_i$. So in that case I get that $L_{ \varepsilon }^{ \nu }$ is $K_\varepsilon$ with $-\frac{x_\nu}{\varepsilon} \psi_i$ instead of just $\psi_i$ where $x_\nu$ is the $\nu$th entry $x$ in $\psi_i ( \frac{ x_i - x }{ \varepsilon })=\psi_i ( \frac{ x_i - \cdot }{ \varepsilon })(x)$. With that I do not understand why Hörmander uses the product $-x_\nu \psi_i$ where $x_\nu$ is the $\nu$th entry of $(x_1,x_2)$.
Is there maybe anything I missed or did not fully understand in the proof?

I think you should treat the $x$ as constant and use the earlier result with $x_1,x_2$ replacing $x$

@CalvinKhor But $x$ is not constant because we consider $\psi_i((x_i-\cdot )/\varepsilon )$ as a function in $x$.

My point is, the equality is true for every fixed $x$. You want to use the result to convert partial wrt epsilon into partial wrt x1 and wrt x2.

@CalvinKhor, indeed I did not consider $x$ as fixed in the equality. But if I do so, I would get $L_\varepsilon^\nu$ as $K_\varepsilon$ by replacing $\psi_1$ or $\psi_2$ with $-(x_1-\cdot )\nu \psi_1$ or $-(x_2-\cdot )\nu \psi_2$ where $(x_i-\cdot )\nu$ is the $\nu$th coordinate of $x_i-\cdot $. I get this result by differentiating $K\varepsilon$ with respect to $\varepsilon$ in its definition at the top.
